# Why even my training data failed during the prediction of libsvm

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm

Currently I'm using libsvm for my one class classification problem. I have 10 samples in my training set, 5 samples in my testing set, both of my training and testing set is scaled by svm_scale, then I use smv_train with the scaled training set for training, and svm_pridict with the scaled testing set for testing. But this problem occurs which makes me very confusing. In the result, why even my training sample fails....

```
Accuracy = 26.666666667% (4/15) (classification)
```

Comment: What kernel are you using? Did you try to tune the parameters?

Comment: I tried with ResilientPropagation

Comment: Can you be more specific about the kernel you are using? ResilientPropagation is not one of the builtin kernels of libsvm. Did you customize the code?  As far as I know Rprop is not a kernel but an algorithm to train ANN. Can you give us details about what exactly you are doing with it?

Comment: oops, sorry my bad, that belongs to my other part of the program, I tried RBF and Sigmoid, I even tried tuning cost and gamma, also the n-fold cross validation but thing didn't turn out well...

Comment: It is very hard to say anything smart without looking at your data and your code.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely you need more data. It's very hard for any algorithm to generalize well on 10 samples, particularly an SVM that is trying to find the subset of data points (i.e. less than 10) that best segregate the data.